# display substring of dataset's cell in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to do create a gridview with dataset, I am hiding some columns after databind. And I also need to display Descriptin column's first 50 characters. How can I do that? here is my code

```
protected void grid_all_posts_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;

     // I want to display only substring in Gridview
     e.Row.Cells[3].Text = e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString().Substring(0,50);
}
```

I hope it is clear

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I am sorry . It gives this error "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string."

Answer (score 2):

Instead of only showing a set number of characters, you might consider using the CSS3 `text-overflow` property. Using this property, you can specify the max-width in pixels, and show an elipses to indicate that more text is available.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;width:150px">
    <span title="Put your full text here">
        This is some really long text. We want it to cut off after a specified number of pixels, and show the elipses to indicate that more text is available.
    </span>
</div>
```

With the above example, you can put the whole text in the tooltip/title, which can be viewed when the user hovers over the text.

Answer (score 0):

this error is for SubString method.
when string length is less than 50 Substring rise exception

replace your last line code with this:

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = (e.Row.Cells[3].Text.Length>50) ? e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString().Substring(0,50) : e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
```

this Code first check length of string and call substring if necessery.